# Angular - How to implement search filter using text input and select Dropdown

Tags: angular

In my Angular-14 application, I want to search or filter data in a table using Text Input field and select dropdown.

I am this JSON response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "pageItems": [
            {
                "id": "1b1b89c0-b18d-4403-b1ba-0a73c1eb2c5c",
                "departmentId": "66306a0e-3369-4e5f-b8ed-d158b147d252", 
                "firstName": "Janet",
                "lastName": "Smith",
                "employeeDepartment": 1,
                "employeeDepartment": {
                    "departmentName": "Account"
                }
            }
        ],
        "pageSize": 10,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "numberOfPages": 1,
        "totalRecord": 1,
        "previousPage": 0
    }
}
```

Then I derive the interface that is shown below.

Interface:

```
export interface PageItem {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  employeeStatus: number;
  employeeDepartment: IEmployeeDepartment;
}

export interface IEmployeeDepartment {
  departmentName: string;
}

export interface IData {
  pageItems: PageItem[];
  pageSize: number;
  currentPage: number;
  numberOfPages: number;
  totalRecord: number;
  previousPage: number;
}

export interface IEmployeeList {
  data: IData;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}
```

Kindly note that the Id are string (GUID from the backend)

Then I have this component.

employee.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, TemplateRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/features/admin/services/employee.service';
import { IData, PageItem, IEmployeeList } from 'src/app/features/admin/models/employee/employee-list';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  allEmployeeList: any[] = [];
  employeeData: PageItem[] = this.allEmployeeList;
  selectedFirstName: string = '';
  selectedDepartment: string = '';
  constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllEmployees();
    this.loadAllDepartments();
  }

  loadAllEmployees() {
    this.employeeService.getAllEmployees().subscribe({
      next: (allEmployeeList = res.data.pageItems;
      this.employeeData = res.data.pageItems;
      this.dataBk = res.data.pageItems;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
      }
    })
  }

  loadAllDepartments() {
    this.employeeService.getAllDepartments().subscribe({
      next: (allDepartmentList = res.data.pageItems;
      this.departmentData = res.data.pageItems;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
      }
    })
  }

  onEmployeeSearch() {
    this.allEmployeeList = this.employeeData.filter(
      (row) =>
        row.firstName
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedFirstName?.toLowerCase()) &&
    (this.selectedStatus !== -1
      ? row.employeeDepartment.departmentName?.includes(this.selectedDepartment)
    );
  }
```

employee.component.html:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="selectedFirstName" (input)="onEmployeeSearch()" placeholder="First Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employeeDepartment">Employee Department</label>
        <ng-container *ngIf="selectedSearchCriteria == 'employeeDepartment'">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="employeeDepartment">Employee Department:</label>
              <ng-select [items]="employeeDepartments"
              [selectOnTab]="true"
              [searchable]="true"
              id="employeeDepartment"
              [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment"
              (change)="onEmployeeSearch()"                    
              bindValue="id"
              bindLabel="departmentName"
              placeholder="Select Employee Department"
              [multiple]="false"
              [clearable]="true"
              formControlName="departmentId">
            </ng-select>                    
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of allEmployeeList>
        <td>{{ row?.firstName || 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ row?.lastName || 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ row?.employeeDepartment?.departmentName || 'N/A' }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using TextInput(selectedFirstName) and Select Dropdown(selectedDepartment) for the search.

When the TextInput input or Dropdown onChange, the application should search through the table and reflect the result.

The TextInput is working, but the Select Dropdown on Change does not have any effect on the table.

How do I correct this and search the table with the Select Dropdown(selectedDepartment) onChange?

Comment: can you add this to stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking good!, the only thing that rings a bell is the last part of this method (the condition where you filter by the selected option).

Can you give this a try?

```
onEmployeeSearch() {
    this.allEmployeeList = this.employeeData.filter(
      (row) =>
        row.firstName
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedFirstName?.toLowerCase()) &&
    (this.selectedStatus === -1 || 
row.employeeDepartment.departmentName?.includes(this.selectedDepartment)
    );
  }
```

That way, using OR you'll get true for every record if there's no selected option, and if there is a selected option, you get to filter stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data using angular pipes. Take a look at the official docs here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes